# Quickbooks PHP API - Customer Name Limit

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am using the PHP SDK for QuickBooks. I create a Customer from the API. When creating I am getting an error says `String length is either shorter or longer than supported by specification, String length specified does not match the supported length. Min:0 Max:25 supported. Supplied length:31`.

This error comes for the `Customer Name`. From the Quick Books interface I can create a customer with a long name. But not from API.

Is there a way to increase this limitation for API.

I looked in the QuickBooks settings. I could not find any field level limitation from there.

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my current findings, we cannot change the limits in Quickbooks to match with our needs. Instead we have to make the same limitations on our side.

Customer name has 50 and Customer First Name has a 25 character limit.

So what we can do is, stick to that limits...

Answer (score 0):

The print_on_check_name field can be used for duplicate and long name entries. Im not sure what the limit is but you can get past the arbitrary 25 for first and last name.

Comment: Yes but the Customer name will still have the issue. Customer name has 50. User First Name has 25. What quickbooks state is these limits cannot be changed.

So we have to limit customer name to 50 chars since that name will be printed on Invoices